# Connecting android to database for a queue app

Tags: php, android, mysql, input

I am relatively new to android and would appreciate any help you guys can provide. 
In my project, I am trying to create a queue system so that whoever is logged into my app has to enter a session name. Entering this session name will move them to a new page with 2 options: question and demonstration. Clicking one of the options, their information will get sent to a database that is holding the session they entered previously. The session is the table in that database.
Basically in my project, I am trying to connect to a database(phpmyadmin)called queue_lnsconnection. This database holds an empty session to be used. I am trying to point to the session. The session is a table in that database.
I am getting an error saying "com.android.volley.volleyerror java.lang.nullpointerexception:attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.string.length()' on a null object reference"

Note that I have created a login page.

StudentActivity2.java

```
public class StudentActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText joinSession;

    // Creating button;
    Button joinButton;

    // Creating Volley RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    // Create string variable to hold the EditText Value.
    String SessionHolder;
    String DecisionHolder;
    String FirstNameHolder;
    String LastNameHolder;

    // Creating Progress dialog.
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String HttpUrl = "http://192.168.2.150:8080/decisionAndroid.php";

    Boolean CheckEditText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student2);
        joinSession = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sessName);

// Assigning ID's to Button.
        joinButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.session);
        // Creating Volley newRequestQueue .
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(StudentActivity2.this);

// Assigning Activity this to progress dialog.
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(StudentActivity2.this);
        joinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if (CheckEditText) {

                    PushedButton();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(StudentActivity2.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }
        });
    }
        public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot() {

            // Getting values from EditText.
            SessionHolder = joinSession.getText().toString().trim();


            // Checking whether EditText value is empty or not.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(SessionHolder)) {

                // If any of EditText is empty then set variable value as False.
                CheckEditText = false;

            } else {

                // If any of EditText is filled then set variable value as True.
                CheckEditText = true;
            }
        }
    public void PushedButton() {

        // Showing progress dialog at user registration time.
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.show();

        // Creating string request with post method.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                        // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        // Matching server responce message to our text.
                        if(ServerResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")) {

                            // If response matched then show the toast.
                            Toast.makeText(StudentActivity2.this, "Logged In Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            // Finish the current Login activity.
                            finish();

                            // Opening the user profile activity using intent.
                            Intent intent=new Intent(StudentActivity2.this,MainActivity.class);

                            // Sending User Email to another activity using intent.
                            intent.putExtra("SessionTAG", SessionHolder);

                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {

                            // Showing Echo Response Message Coming From Server.
                            Toast.makeText(StudentActivity2.this, ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                        // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                        Toast.makeText(StudentActivity2.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                // Creating Map String Params.
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // Adding All values to Params.
                // The firs argument should be same sa your MySQL database table columns.
                params.put("id", SessionHolder);
                params.put("decision", DecisionHolder);




                return params;
            }

        };
        // Creating RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(StudentActivity2.this);

        // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
    }
```

CheckSession.php

```
<?php

//Define your host here.
$HostName = "localhost";

//Define your database username here.
$HostUser = "root";

//Define your database password here.
$HostPass = "";

//Define your database name here.
$DatabaseName = "queue_lnsconnection";

?>
```

decisionAndroid.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'CheckSession.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

  $First_Name = $_POST['firstname'];
 $Last_Name = $_POST['lastname'];
  $Bench = $_POST['bench'];
 $Decision = $_POST['decision'];


 $CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM queue_template";
 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL);
 $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
 //if(isset($check))

 if($row>0){
echo "Data Matched";
}
else{
echo "Bench not valid";
}

}else{
echo "Check Again";
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I tried to minimize the code as much as possible but im not really sure what the issue is.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does echo back? There are 3 of them in your php.

Comment: `if(isset($check))` < that could throw you back a false positive. Best to either count if it's more than 0, or use num_rows to check if there is a matching row.

Comment: so i edited the php file. the reason i changed my SELECT statement is because my android is layed out in a way as im basically inputting the session name and checking if it exists as a table in the database. Once it recognizes it exists, store the user info and move to the next Android page. Is that alright?

Comment: First, `mysql_num_rows` doesn't mix with the mysqli_ api, you need `mysqli_num_rows`. However, I'd get rid of `mysqli_fetch_array()` and only use `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Comment: made those changes. It might have something to do with my android code as I am still getting the errors

Comment: Which errors are those? If this is Android related, I can't be of much help.

Comment: ya they are  :/. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Android Cannot read Web page Content, try to use JSON response like below

In your **PHP file**

```
    <?php 
// do Connection to DB if 
(isset($_POST['bench'])) {

 $bench = $_POST['bench'];

 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM `queue_template ` WHERE bench = : bench";

// Prepare the SQL statement.
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sql);

// Bind our bench value to the : bench parameter.
$stmt->bindValue(': bench', $bench);

// Execute the statement.
$stmt->execute();

// Fetch the row / result.
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// If num is bigger than 0, the bench already exists.
if($row['num'] > 0){

// Do your code Here like inserting in SQL or some Functions...
...
 // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Bench not exist.";

// echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
       }else{
       // bench already exist.

    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Bench already exist.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);


}

} //Closing if statement 

?>
```

And in your Android Studio Add this class to your Activity class and import Json in Gradle

```
implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
```

here's the class

```
private  class CheckBench extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String bench = // get Value from EditText or whatever

    // You can add more Strings Ints or anything here


    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PostShow.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Checking...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //add your Strings Ints... as params here
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bench", bench));



        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(HttpUrl, "POST", param);
        try {
            int success = json.getInt("success");
            String messages = json.getString("message");
            if (success == 1) {

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), messages,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                String messager = json.getString("message");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), messager,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }



            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String url_link) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        COMMENTAIRE.setText("");
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bench CHecked",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using Volley for my registration and login page(which are both functioning) Would JSON effect those pages? Also(from a suggestion above), i edited the php file. the reason i changed my SELECT statement is because my android is laid out in a way as im basically inputting the session name on one android page and checking if it exists as a table in the database. Once it recognizes it exists, store the user info and move to the next Android page.

Comment: You can use both of them, after checking if the user exists with my example, you can make statement with JSON response if equals 0 automatically inside php you insert the user into sql then you move to other android page

Comment: I added this to the top of my class: import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject; and in the build.gradle(Module: app) i added the implementation in dependencies.Im getting a lot of errors in OnPreExecute() with regards to pDialog saying cannot resolve symbol. Im also getting the same errors at the doInBackground for NameValuePair, BasicNameValuePair and jsonParser